# How to remove an eventListener (window.removeEventListener) in Vue 2, when certain condition is met

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, event-handling, event-listener

Code :-

```js
<template>
// html
</template>

<script>
import _ from "lodash";

 data() {
    return {
      renderComponent: false,
    };
  },
 watch: {
// when this property is true, want to stop calling scroll event with this.onScroll method
    renderComponent(val) {
      if(val === true) {
        console.log("////////I am removing you");
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
      }
    }
  },
 methods: {
    onScroll() {
      console.log("I am called////////");
      let similarTickerHeading = this.$refs.similarTicker;
      if(similarTickerHeading) {
       let margin = similarTickerHeading.getBoundingClientRect().top;
       let innerHeigth = window.innerHeight;
        console.log("Window Screen", innerHeigth);
        console.log("Component located", margin);
       
// when this condition is true, I want to stop listening for the scroll event with this (onScroll method)
       if(margin - innerHeigth < 850) {
          console.log("I should start loading the actual component");
          this.renderComponent = true;
          this.$vs.loading.close("#loader-example > .con-vs-loading");
          // removing eventListener for scrolling with the onScroll Method
          window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
       }
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.renderComponent = false;
     this.$vs.loading({
        container: "#loader-example",
        type: "point",
        scale: 0.8,
      });

    this.$nextTick(function() {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', _.throttle(this.onScroll,250));
      this.onScroll();
    })
  },
 beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
  },
</script>
```

In the above code, I want to stop listening for the scroll event with `onScroll` method when  my `if` block in `onScroll` method becomes true. But, still, the `onScroll` method gets called whenever I scroll even though when I tried to remove the `eventListener`. I even created a watcher to remove the `eventListener`, yet the method keeps on getting called on scroll.

How can I remove the scroll eventListener with `onScroll` method ?

**UPDATE** : If I remove throttling and cut out `_.throttle`, the scroll event does get removed. Due to the use of `_.throttle`, I cannot remove the scroll event listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function reference passed to `window.addEventListener()` must be the same reference passed to `window.removeEventListener()`. In your case, there are two different references because you've wrapped one of them with `_.throttle()`.

#### Solution

Cache the function reference passed to `addEventListener()` so that it could be used later for `removeEventListener()`:

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
              
    this._scrollHandler = _.throttle(this.onScroll, 250)

    this.$nextTick(() => {                        
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this._scrollHandler);
      this.onScroll();
    })
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
                                                    
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this._scrollHandler);
  },
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-remove-global-event-listener?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FScrollListener.vue)